# What is globalOrWindow object and whats its purpose?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I recently encountered this error while trying to run my react-native example.

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'globalOrWindow.navigator.userAgent.toString')`

So, what is globalOrWindow object and when does this error occur?

Comment: Please provide reproducible code sample (stackblitz, fiddle ...)

Comment: It's the [global scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object), which in the browser would be the window

Comment: I cant provide a code sample because you have to configure many things like attaching the project to FCM and configuring the manifest file to enable push notifications and the only thing that causes this error is when I wrap my App into the provider and try to run the application.

Comment: So I only posted this file which you can check from https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-js-native-hihz52?file=index.js